# WPF Points databinding issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, points

I am developing interactive chart library...and application, which use it.

In application, I have a `ListView` with `Points` of the `CurrentItem`.

```
public Point CurrentPoint
  {
   get { return myCurrentPoint; }
   set
   {
    myCurrentPoint = value;
    base.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPoint");
   }
  }
```

At the same panel, I have two textboxes for editing point's coordinates:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPoint.X, Mode=TwoWay}" 
       Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="80" Margin="5"/>
```

My big problem is, that `Point` is a structure...so it's passing by value.

If I change `X` coordinate in textbox...it doesn't change databind `Point`.

How can I solve this problem?
Should I write my own `Point` class, and `Line` class too, because of her `Points` are `PointCollection` of `Point`?

If it's needed, I can post more code :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a combined control that changes the Point instead of the x-and y-component of the `Point`. Then you can bind to your `Point`-property and binding will work as expected. Furthermore, you have probably a nicer UI.

You can create a `UserControl`, add two text-boxes and add a DependencyProperty-`Point` to this control. Everytime the contents of one of the textboxes changes, set the `Point`-property to its new value.

```
public class PointInputBox : UserControl{

  public static readonly DependencyProperty PointProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Point", typeof(Point), typeof(PointInputBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0,0),FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


  public Point Point {
    get { return (Point)GetValue(PointProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PointProperty, value); }
  }

  // Add here event handlers for changes of your input boxes and set 
  //  the Point-value accordingly
```

Comment: Thanks, at the moment, i do a workaround for it. If i change coordinate in the textbox, my view model change Point in pointcollection based on currently selected index in ListView.
I am going to try your way. It seems more flexible, and nicer.